# Factory Returns Interface

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interface

I’m creating a ticketing system where a request is submitted by a user and it ultimately answered by an SME. There are two types of request that can be made within this system; SupportHardwareEnquiry and AlternateDriverEnquiry.

As they share similar characteristics, I’ve created an interface called IRequest

```
public interface IRequest
{
    int RequestId { get; }
    State State { get; }
    RequestHeader RequestHeader { get; }
    InterimDialogue InterimDialogue { get; }       
    RequestSolution RequestSolution { get; }
}
```

Where the two request types differ slightly, I’ve created two separate interfaces that both implement IRequest.

The interface for the SupportHardwareEnquiry is as per follows

```
public interface ISupportHardwareEnquiry : IRequest
{
    SupportingInformation SupportingInformation { get; }
    ProblemTask ProblemTask { get; }
}
```

Finally the concrete class implements ISupportHardwareEnquiry

```
public class SupportHardwareEnquiry : ISupportHardwareEnquiry
{     
    public int RequestId { get; private set; }
    public State State { get; private set; }
    public RequestHeader RequestHeader { get; private set; }
    public SupportingInformation SupportingInformation { get; private set; }
    public ProblemTask ProblemTask { get; private set; }
    public InterimDialogue InterimDialogue { get; private set; }
    public RequestSolution RequestSolution { get; private set; }

 // etc ...
}
```

To instantiate a SupportHardwareEnquiry object, a RequestFactory has been used

```
public class RequestFactory : IRequestFactory
{
    public IRequest CreateSupportHardwareEnquiry()
    {
        return new SupportHardwareEnquiry();
    }


    public IRequest CreateAlternateDriverEnquiry()
    {
        return new AlternateDriverEnquiry();
    }
}
```

I also use a repository to list the requests, and reconstituting individual requests.

```
public interface IRequestRepository
{
    IEnumerable<IRequest> GetAllRequests();


    IRequest GetAlternateDriverEnquiry(int id);


    IRequest GetSupportHardwareEnquiry(int id);
}
```

While I can use the GetAllRequests() method because it relies only on information in RequestHeader, the problem that I’m having is that upon using my RequestFactory or Repository to instantiate or reconstitute a single object.

Because they return an IRequest, there are properties of the SupportHardwareEnquiry (i.e. SupportingInformation and ProblemTask) that I can’t access.

I can cast to the concrete type:

```
        IRequest supportHardwareEnquiry = factory.CreateSupportHardwareEnquiry();
        var request = (SupportHardwareEnquiry)supportHardwareEnquiry;
```

But now seeing as how I need to know ahead of time, what I want to get back, there doesn’t seem much point in doing the rest.

I am aware that I could have used inheritance instead, but how should I approach these design situations when sometimes I want to treat them as general requests, and sometimes as specific types of request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If CreateSupportHardwareEnquiry() always will return an ISupportHardwareEnquiry, just typehint it in the method definition.

```
public class RequestFactory : IRequestFactory
{
    public ISupportHardwareEnquiry CreateSupportHardwareEnquiry()
    {
        return new SupportHardwareEnquiry();
    }


    public IRequest CreateAlternateDriverEnquiry()
    {
        return new AlternateDriverEnquiry();
    }
}
```